# Geometry of $|A||B| = |A * B| + |A \times B|$

Tags: geometry, vectors, inner-products, cross-product

Geometry of $(|A||B|)^2 = |A * B|^2 + |A \times B|^2$ where $*$ represents the dot product

This identity is easy to verify algebraically once we recall that $|A * B| = |A||B|||\cos(\theta)|$ and $|A \times B| = |A||B||\sin(\theta)|$. Can somebody help me understand this identity in a more geometric way? Why should we expect these values to form a pythagorean triple? Thank you

Comment: Look at Geometric Algebra : its main tenet is that you can multiply vectors (and not only their magnitudes) in a significant way :
$a b = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$ where the wedge is in 3D the dual (in some sense) of the cross-product, but has a useful definition in higher (or lower) dimensions.

Comment: You are forgetting squares in the identity

Comment: right, fixed. thanks

Answer (score 3):

When $B$ is a unit, $A\cdot B$ is (the magnitude of) the *projection* of $A$ onto $B$, and $|A\times B|$ is (the magnitude of) the *rejection* of $A$ from $B$.

The projection of a vector onto another is probably familiar, but the rejection is likely less so. The *rejection of $A$ from $B$* is formed by

1. Forming the plane $P$ spanned by $A, B$.
2. Finding the orthogonal complement $B'$ *within* $P$ of the span of $B$; in other words $B' = (\mathbb RB)^\perp\cap P$.
3. Projecting $A$ onto $B'$.

You'll see easily that the projection and rejection form legs of a right triangle, and their hypotenuse, i.e. their sum, is $A$.

So the real mystery is how the cross product is related to rejection. What we can notice is that the rejection is $A$ minus the projection,
$$
  A - \frac{A\cdot B}{|B|^2}B,
$$
but $B\cdot B/|B|^2 = 1$ so this can be written
$$
  B\times\frac{(A\times B)}{|B|^2}.
$$
Notice the similarity with projection. When $B$ is a unit we can write
$$
  A = B(A\cdot B) + B\times(A\times B).
$$
Both terms are clearly orthogonal to each other, so
$$
  |A|^2 = |B(A\cdot B)|^2 + |B\times(A\times B)|^2.
$$
The first term is of course $(A\cdot B)^2$. For the second term, $B$ is orthogonal to $A\times B$ so
$$
  |B\times(A\times B)|^2 = |B|^2|A\times B|^2 = |A\times B|^2.
$$
All together
$$
  |A|^2 = (A\cdot B)^2 + |A\times B|^2,
$$
as desired.

---

This is less mysterious once you realize the cross product is a stand-in for the plane $P$ via an orthogonal vector; algebraically it is the Hodge star of the exterior product:
$$
  A\times B = \star(A\wedge B).
$$
The Hodge star takes $k$-vectors (in this case a $2$-vector or *bivector*) representing $k$-dimensional subspaces $X$ to $(n-k)$-vectors (in this case $1$-vectors or just *vectors*) representing $X^\perp$, where $n$ is the overall dimension of the space. Notice how this construction of the cross product is specific to $n=3$.

As Imsteffan notes in the comments there is a very close connection here with *geometric algebra*, which is a Clifford algebra interpreted (canonically) as a *geometric product* on the exterior algebra (the algebra of *multivectors*, $k$-vectors for all $k$, with the exterior product). Roughly, the Clifford algebra for $A \mapsto |A|^2$ is the associative algebra where the only rules are $A^2 = |A|^2$ and anything that can be derived from that. We see that vectors have inverses:
$$
  A^{-1} = A/A^2 = A/|A|^2.
$$
If I also state as fact that the geometric product of two vectors is
$$
  AB = A\cdot B + A\wedge B
$$
which you can think of as a "bag" containing a scalar $A\cdot B$ and a bivector $A\wedge B$, then we see
$$
  A = AB^{-1}B = (A\cdot B^{-1})B + (A\wedge B^{-1})B.
$$
The first term is exactly the projection onto $B$:
$$
  (A\cdot B^{-1})B = \frac{A\cdot B}{|B|^2}B.
$$
This means the second term *must* also be a vector and be the rejection from $B$. As we know, $A\wedge B$ is related to $A\times B$, and in fact we now see
$$
  (A\wedge B^{-1})B = B\times(A\times B^{-1}).
$$

Alternatively, there is a very natural way to extend the inner product to an inner product on all multivectors, and which makes $k$-vectors and $l$-vectors orthogonal when $k\ne l$. Then we directly have
$$
  |AB|^2 = |A\cdot B|^2 + |A\wedge B|^2.
$$
$|\cdot|^2$ is multiplicative on products of vectors, and the Hodge star is an isometry so
$$
  |A|^2|B|^2 = (A\cdot B)^2 + |A\times B|^2.
$$